# Is it possible to return only one instance of each ID in a view?

Tags: postgresql, view

I am trying to work out how I would ensure I only get one instance of each user and their ID when I try to do an inner join on my source table.
The source data is a series of user names and IDs

```
userid  username
 1      alice
 2      bob
 3      charley
 4      dave
 5      robin
 6      jon
 7      lou
 8      scott
```

I have had to write the algorithm in python, to make sure I only get one set of user data matches with another (so we can make sure each user's data is used once in each round)
We store the pairings, and how many rounds have been completed successfully after the tests, but I'd like to try and shortcut the process
I can get all the results, but I want to find a better way to remove each matched pair from the results so they can't be matched again.

```
select u.user_id, u.user, ur.user_id, ur.user
    from userResults u inner join userResults ur
on u.user_id < ur.user_id
and (u.user_id, ur.user_id) not in
(select uid, uid2 from rounds)
where u.match <= ur.match and ((u.user_id) not in %s
and ur.user_id not in %s) limit 1;
```

I've tried making materialised views with a unique constraint, but it doesn't seem to affect it - I get each possible pairing once, rather than each user paired only once

I'm trying to work out how I only get 4 results, in the right order. 
Every time I look at the underlying code, I can't help but think there's a better way to write it natively in SQL rather than having to iterate over results in python.

*edit*

assuming each user has been matched 0 or more times, you might have a situtation where user_id's 1-4 have rounds set to 1, and matches set to 1, and the remaining 4 have rounds set to 1 and no matches.

I have a view which will return a default value of 0 and 0 for rounds and matches if they haven't yet played, and you can't assume all rounds entered have met with a match.

If the first 4 have all matched, and have generated rounds, user 1 and user 2 have already met and matched in a round, so they won't be matched again, so user 1 will match user 3 (or 4) and user 2 will match user 4 (or 3)
The issue I'm having is that when I remove limit, and iterate through manually - the first three matches I always get are: 2,4 then 1,3, then 2,3 (rather than 5,7 or 6,8)

---

Adding the sample data and current rounds
table rounds

```
uid     uid2
1       2
3       4
```

userresults view

```
user_id user    rounds  score
1   alice   1   0
2   bob     1   1
3   charley 1   1
4   dave    1   0
5   robin   0   0
6   jon     0   0
7   lou     0   0
8   scott   0   0
```

I'm currently getting results like:

```
2,4
2,3
1,3
1,4
4,6
```

...

These are all valid results, but I would like to limit them to a single instance of each ID in each column, so just the first match of each valid pairing.

I've created a new view to try and simplify things a but, and populated it with dummy data and tried to generate matches
All these matches are valid, and I'm trying to add some form of filter or restriction to bring it back to sensible numbers.

```
777;"Bongo Steveson";779;"Drongo Mongoson"
777;"Bongo Steveson";782;"Cheesey McHamburger"
777;"Bongo Steveson";780;"Buns Mattburger"
779;"Drongo Mongoson";782;"Cheesey McHamburger"
779;"Drongo Mongoson";781;"Hamburgler Bunburger"
775;"Bob Jobsworth";777;"Bongo Steveson"
778;"Mongo Bongoson";779;"Drongo Mongoson"
775;"Bob Jobsworth";778;"Mongo Bongoson"
778;"Mongo Bongoson";781;"Hamburgler Bunburger"
775;"Bob Jobsworth";782;"Cheesey McHamburger"
775;"Bob Jobsworth";781;"Hamburgler Bunburger"
775;"Bob Jobsworth";780;"Buns Mattburger"
776;"Steve Bobson";777;"Bongo Steveson"
776;"Steve Bobson";779;"Drongo Mongoson"
776;"Steve Bobson";782;"Cheesey McHamburger"
776;"Steve Bobson";778;"Mongo Bongoson"
776;"Steve Bobson";781;"Hamburgler Bunburger"
780;"Buns Mattburger";782;"Cheesey McHamburger"
780;"Buns Mattburger";781;"Hamburgler Bunburger"
```

I still can't work out a sensible way to restrict these values, and it's driving me nuts.
I've implemented a solution in code but I'd really like to see if I can get this working in native Postgres.
At this point I'm monkeying around with a new test database schema, and this is my view - the adding unique to the index generates an error, and I can't add a check constraint to a materialised view (grrrr)

Comment: Please show the rest of the sample data, and show expected results. Right now you're only showing half the picture and there's a lot of guessing involved. What pairings? What rounds? There's something assumed here that you're not explaining, and half the question makes no sense if you don't know whatever that unexplained thing is. Why should you get only 4 results? From what?

Comment: Wild stab in the dark: You are attempting to make pairs of users, and you wish to return only one pairing for each user, such that if you return `(a, b)` you don't want to also return `(b, a)` or `(a, c)`.

Comment: Please add the expected output based on your sample data.

Comment: Hi guys - I've added some sample information and expected outputs

Answer (score 0):

You can try joining sub query to ensure distinct record from  user table.

```
select * from any_table t1 
inner join(
  select distinct userid,username from  source_table  
) t2 on t1.userid=t2.userid;
```

Comment: Hi Code-Monk, Sadly - that doesn't remove any of the already matched items - I'd rather have Postgres build the appropriate sets, rather than having python do the data manipulation

Comment: Hi scott, Can you share sample table with some data and results you want?. So that we can work on your query accordingly.